# How to add a mailto box with attachment

Tags: wordpress

We have a website for our Translation Company, build under wordpress and will later be move to a .com domain. For now, we want our client to submit documents online, and therefore we should add a sort of a box where they can click and attach their file, file up their name a comment.

```
http://nytseoul.wordpress.com/
It's on the second page "Submit your documents"
```

We tried some pluggins that didn't work, if anyone has an idea, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use contact form 7 plugin. It is very easy to use to upload files in contact form.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/

*Contact Form 7 can manage multiple contact forms, plus you can customize the form and the mail contents flexibly with simple markup. The form supports Ajax-powered submitting, CAPTCHA, Akismet spam filtering and so on.*